# Proof of weak law for triangular arrays

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Durrett's Theorem 2.2.6, he gives
[image]

For the underlined section, I argue this by the following:

- If $\bar{S}_n=S_n$ and $\left|\frac{\bar{S}_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|\leq \epsilon$, then $\left|\frac{S_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|\leq \epsilon$
- Reversing direction, if $\left|\frac{S_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|> \epsilon$, then $\bar{S}_n\neq S_n$ or $\left|\frac{\bar{S}_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|>\epsilon$
- We can then take sets and apply countable subadditivity to get the underlined.

However, while this reasoning appears correct (is it actually?), it's pretty artificial and I wouldn't come up with the underlined based on it.  Is there some other proof that is less artificial and could lead us to realizing this inequality?

Comment: Denote $A = \left\{\left|\frac{S_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|> \epsilon\right\}$, $B = \left\{\left|\frac{\bar S_n-a_n}{b_n}\right|> \epsilon\right\}$, $C = \{S_n = \bar S_n\}$. Then 
$$
P(A) = P(A\setminus C) + P(A\cap C)\le P(\Omega\setminus C) + P(B).
$$

Comment: Thanks.  Was my original argument correct?

Comment: Yes, perfectly correct.  There's nothing artificial.